# What is the plot of Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm slightly interested in the story of Guild Wars 2, but not interested enough to click through every dialogue and play through every living story. Can someone provide a summary of the events so far?

Comment: If you find the lore interesting, there are also novels: https://www.guildwars2.com/en/shop/guild-wars-2-novels/

Comment: I had no idea there are whole novels, that's actually interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read through your [Story Journal](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Story_Journal) after completing instances if you want to get through them as fast as possible and learn more about them later.

Comment: Please refer to the edit summary. Answers that rely on external sources are not allowed.